# How to make a video/gif transparent on p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to get a video playing on the canvas, and also make it transparent.

I tried the tint() function, but it only seems to work on images.

```
let vid;
let button;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 1000);
    vid = createVideo("final1.mp4"); 

    vid.hide(); 

    button = createButton('play');
    button.position(100,200); 
    button.mousePressed(toggleVid);
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
}

function toggleVid(){
    tint(255, 126);
    vid.show(); 
    vid.play(); 
    vid.position(100,300); 
}
```

I want the video or gif to be transparent, not working.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a video transparent you can display it on the canvas and use tint.

Here is an example that combines code from these three p5.js examples, [dom-video](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video.html), [dom-video-canvas](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-canvas.html) and [tint](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/tint). The code draws a red circle on the canvas and then sets the tint and draws the video offset by 10 pixels so you can see the transparency.

```
let playing = false;
let fingers;
let button;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300,300)
  fingers = createVideo(['fingers.mov']);
  fingers.hide();
  button = createButton('play');
  button.mousePressed(toggleVid); // attach button listener
}

function draw() {
  background(150);
  fill(255,0,0,200);
  ellipse(50,50,100,100);
  tint(255, 127); // make the video partially transparent without changing the color
  image(fingers, 10, 10); // draw the video frame to canvas
}

// plays or pauses the video depending on current state
function toggleVid() {
  if (playing) {
    fingers.pause();
    button.html('play');
  } else {
    fingers.loop();
    button.html('pause');
  }
  playing = !playing;
}
```

[Run the sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/charlie-openschool/sketches/AZP3ciMid)